# Import csv module file not opening

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open a csv file using the csv module and then trying to read some data off of it using this code.

```
import csv



def file_open():
    input_file=str(input('enter the input file to use'))

    while True:
        try:
            with open(input_file,'r') as grades:
                grades_reader=csv.reader(grades, delimiter=',')
                break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('FileNotFoundError')
            input_file=str(input('enter the input file to use'))

    row_num=1
    for row in grades_reader:
        print('row',row_num,row)
        row_num+=1
    


file_open()
```

and the file opening seems to be working until it gets to the part where it has to read the data and then it gives me an i/o error saying the file is closed. I am quite new to python and would appreciate any insight on what I did wrong.
also input_file is meant to allow the user to pick any file but I will only be using it to call one file called Grades.csv if that information will help

EDIT: traceback error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\musta\OneDrive\Documents\computer assignment programs\program 4\Program4.py", line 24, in <module>
    file_open()
  File "C:\Users\musta\OneDrive\Documents\computer assignment programs\program 4\Program4.py", line 18, in file_open
    for row in grades_reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Please post the traceback error message. Its easier to spot the problem when we have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is closed because your `break` ends the loop, and the `with` body, therefore closing the file

You should keep that file reading code within the `with` indentation.

A `csv.reader` doesn't load the file into some in-memory list

Comment: thank you for helping me with that. i was wondering if there was any way to authenticate the file existing then if i removed the break since the while loop would simply keep going then. Also if I wanted to open the file and then use it elsewhere to do calculations using data form within the file then how would i go about doing that?

Comment: You can still use a break, you just cannot reference the file handle outside the `with` body. You can create and use other variables that don't require the file, though